# Firefox extension - how do we check if this is a content script?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-extension

We develop extensions for Firefox. The script needs to know if it is a content script or a background script (sometimes the same script can be both a content script and a background script). We tried to do it with the following code:

```
if (typeof exports === 'undefined') {
    // we're in a content script.
} else {
    // we're in a background script.
}
```

<strike>But the problem is that `typeof exports` is not `'undefined'` in some content scripts. Is there a better way to know when we are in a content script?</strike>

**Edit**: I has a mistake and actually `typeof exports` is `'undefined'` in the content script. So maybe checking `typeof exports` is a reliable way to identify content scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that came up into my mind - include some separate file to extension as content script, that will have global variable. E.g. file *content_script_definition.js*:

```
isContentScript = true;
```

And then use next code:

```
if (typeof isContentScript !== 'undefined' && isContentScript) {
    // we're in a content script.
} else {
    // we're in a background script.
}
```

Maybe there is some documented functionality, not sure about this...

Comment: I think this is a fine way - you could go looking for known content script globals like 'self' / 'addon' but these could be defined as globals in other js scopes for valid reasons. Using this technique you're being explicit about how to detect being run in a content script.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```js
if(String(this).indexOf("Sandbox") >= 0){
  //main.js
}
else{
  //content script
}
```